# Preferences Shuts Down Blender

Tags: customization

I am trying to simply change some preferences, but each time I click on "User Preferences", Blender just turns itself off. I can't make any adjustments, and am missing out on functionality as a result. Could you help me understand why this is happening and what to do, as I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall Blender several times to avoid this problem, but have been unsuccessful.

Sincerely,

Cole

Answer (score 0):

You probably have outdated drivers, please try updating your drivers, or you could try going into user preferences by changing 3d view-port window to user preferences